# Как при наведении мыши на одну часть сайта изменить другую часть на JS

Tags: javascript

Как сделать ефект затемнения (background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); правой стороны  сайта (div id="man") при наведении мышки на левую (div id="woman") и наоборот затемнить левую сторону при наведении мышки на правую? На языке JS с помощью условного оператора if? Вот так как на картинке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для этого не особо то нужен js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно таким образом. А там уже с классами и цветами сам разберешься, я думаю. Хотя !important юзать очень плохая привычка, я использовал его для примера.

```js
let left = document.getElementById('left');
let right = document.getElementById('right');

left.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  right.classList.add('dark');
});
left.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  right.classList.remove('dark');
});

right.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  left.classList.add('dark');
});
right.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  left.classList.remove('dark');
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #990000!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS only

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left-front, #left-back,
#right-front, #right-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#right-front,
#right-back {
  right: 0;
}

#right-front, #left-front {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events:none;
}

#right-back:hover ~ #left-front,
#left-back:hover ~ #right-front {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="left-back"></div>
<div id="right-back"></div>
<div id="left-front"></div>
<div id="right-front"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще такой вариант на CSS:

```css
#main {display: flex; cursor: pointer}
#main div {width: 50%}

.img {width: 100%;}

#main:hover #women {filter: grayscale(); transition: 0.2s;}

#women:hover ~ #men {filter: grayscale(); transition: 0.2s;}
#main #women:hover {filter: none; transition: 0.2s;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="women">
    <img class="img" src="https://gyazo.com/8fb1ec2e47fe45c1b79eb69faf4df6c4.png">
  </div>
  <div id="men">
    <img class="img" src="https://gyazo.com/652b8bd22aec3ffd9bf852e36e4a7df5.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Или...

```css
#main {display: flex; cursor: pointer}
#main div {width: 50%}

.img {width: 100%;}

#women, #men {width: 50%; height: 500px; background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
#women {background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/8fb1ec2e47fe45c1b79eb69faf4df6c4.png');}
#men {background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/652b8bd22aec3ffd9bf852e36e4a7df5.png');}

#main:hover #women {filter: grayscale(); transition: 0.2s;}

#women:hover ~ #men {filter: grayscale(); transition: 0.2s;}
#main #women:hover {filter: none; transition: 0.2s;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="women"></div>
  <div id="men"></div>
</div>
```

Можно играться тут → [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/j5ka1bgs/)